# How can I chmod/chown a specific list of files?

Tags: command-line, unix

I want to write a .sh script to setup some folder permissions, but was wonder if I can run something like:

```
chown -644 ./one;/two;/three
```

to chown a list of folders, rather than calling chown multiple times.

Also, would there be a way to chown a list of files, and exclude some others, like for example:

```
chown -R -664 ./*;!./cache
```

I hope my pseudo command lines make sense.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Almost all Unix tools accept a list of files as non-option arguments. As usual, the different arguments have to be separated by space:

```
chmod 644 one two three
```

In your second example, if you're using Bash, a simple

```
chmod -R 644 !(cache)
```

will be enough.

This approach requires extended pattern matching. If it's disabled, you can enable it with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

See: [Bash Reference Manual # Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: The answer is correct but the first two examples have an error. Chown should specify a user, not octal permissions. Chmod should specify octal permissions. In the examples, chown should be changed to chmod or the octal permissions should be changed to a username. For example: chown dennis one two three

Comment: Can `chmod... !(cache)` fail if there are lots of arguments?

Answer (score 5):

Make a list of filenames in `./list-of-filenames-to-change.txt` and then run:

```
chmod g+w `cat list-of-filenames-to-change.txt`
```

or use the method described by others here:

```
chmod 644 one two three
```

or go to town with the first option but manipulate each line in the file (in this example: replace " /" (WITH whitespace before) by " ./"):

```
chmod g+w `sed 's/ \// .\//' update-writable.txt`
```

Answer (score 3):

If the files you want to modify are in one directory you can ls them with the needed pattern.

e.g. I need all downloaded .run files in pwd to be changed to executable:

```
chmod +x `ls *.run`
```

Answer (score 2):

regex for the [win!](http://dave.thehorners.com/tech-talk/programming/313-regular-expressions-regex)

using find is the best way I can think of outside of using the regex that may already exist in your particular shell or within the app you are using itself.
first, I tried:

```
touch one&touch two &touch three&find -name "one|two|three" -exec chown -644 {} \;
```

But, you'll find that the pipe doesn't work in this case.  Another sad thing to learn...like learning chmod,chown,chgrp,et. al. doesn't support multi-file/regex selection/exclusion itself...
The solution I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111067/regex-match-either-string-in-linux-find-command

```
find \( -name one -o -name two -o -name three \) -exec chown -644 {} \;
```

so, not so much regex for the win, but at least we have a way to inject a list of files into the args of a program in a one liner.

you'll note that you need to escape the () meta-characters, and the addition of the -o parameter for each additional name...

other links and content from me which might interest you along your travels:
[Various tidbits - notes from korn bourne and friends. - Dave Horner's Website](http://dave.thehorners.com/tech-talk/unix-linux-bsd-osx-etc/66-various-tidbits)

Cheers.
--dave

Comment: KISS win, Keep it simple and stupid ! no need to complex things that can  be still clean and easy.